# posted Zelle transfer

Tags: wire-transfer

I have received a transfer  via Zelle on Thursday last week, and today Monday is still not available, it is shown below the "authorized" transfers as "posted" but not having the "authorized" sign makes me wonder if it is possible not to receive the money.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're enrolled your Zelle profile (as explained below). Zelle explains that it could take one to three business days after enrollment for the money to be available. If you enrolled on Thursday, it could take until Tuesday to receive your funds.

> If the recipient is not yet enrolled, it may take between one to three business days after the recipient has enrolled for the money to be available. This is a security feature of Zelle designed to reduce risk and protect you whenever you’re sending and receiving money. If it has been more than three days, we recommend confirming that you have fully enrolled your Zelle profile, and that you entered the correct email address or U.S. mobile number and provided this to the sender. ([source](https://www.zellepay.com/support/how-long-does-it-take-to-receive-money-with-zelle))